# Get the 5th occurance for a number using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a number like the following `201106260157.png` and i want to get the first four numbers and then the second two after the first four

what i did to get the first four is the following expression

```
preg_match('/^\d{4}/', $file, $matches);    // result 2011
```

how can i get the next two numbers (06) ? after the first four i just matched using regular expressions?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use capture groups for each part:

```
preg_match('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})/', $file, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the first 4 numbers, `$matches[2]` contains the next 2.

You could also use `substr()`, but it won't check whether the characters are digits, you'd have to do that after getting the substrings.

Comment: Not directly related to the initial question since the OP seems to be asking about PHP, but `sed(1)` has a much nicer way of doing it.  Watch: `echo 1234567 | sed 's/[0-9]/*/5'`.

Comment: I don't see how that solves the same problem. That replaces the 5th match of the regexp. The OP doesn't want to replace anything, he just wants to extract parts of the original string.

Answer (score 3):

Use capturing group.

```
preg_match('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})/', $file, $matches);
```

From that, get the first four digits from group index 1 and the following two digits from group index 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wC1mW9/1)

**OR**

Use preg_match_all,

```
preg_match_all('~^\d{4}|(?<=^\d{4})\d{2}~', $file, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wC1mW9/2)